# How to Get user profile picture URL by Facebook Id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

After Recent Facebook changes 
**http://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookId + "/picture?type=square**  
is downloading image instead of displaying image.


https://graph.facebook.com/118844755560695/picture?type=large

Answer (score 0):

Do an API request with one of the SDKs and you will get the following JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "is_silhouette": true,
    "url": "https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yL/r/HsTZSDw4avx.gif"
  }
}
```

The `url` is what you can use for display.

Comment: If this is generated with the api, the link will be temporary only.

Comment: of course, the cdn urls should never be stored, facebook does not guarantee that they stay the same.